# list of tuples from list of lists Python

Tags: python

**Input:** List of lists `[[1, 2, 3], [5, 6]]` something like that.

**Required Output**: list of combinations in tuples `[(1), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (5), (5, 6)]`.

I can imagine how to solve this, but I guess Python has some handy built-in functions for that

Comment: To know what the bar to improve on is (and so we know you tried something), what's your current solution?

Comment: `[tuple(seq[:i]) for seq in list_of_lists for i in range(1,len(seq)+1)]`

Comment: my solution was to use for-loop for nested lists to create tuples on each iteration. New tuple will be created as previous one with addition of new element from list

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there isn't a built-in function, but it's easy to achieve that result with a list-comprehension:

```
[tuple(seq[:i]) for seq in list_of_lists for i in range(1,len(seq)+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want *all* combinations of each sublist, you can use [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to help:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]

def powerset(seq, empty=True):
    for i in range(0 if empty else 1, len(seq)+1):
        for comb in combinations(seq, i):
            yield comb

out = list(chain.from_iterable(powerset(l, False) for l in lst))
```

This gives:

```
out == [(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3),   
        (4,), (5,), (4, 5)]
```

You could modify this to filter just the tuples matching the start of each sublist, but if that's all you want Bakuriu's solution is more efficient.

Comment: From his example I think he doesn't want all combinations, but only the "starting segments".